# Open graph meta tags in header for facebook not being read

Tags: facebook, tags, facebook-opengraph, meta

Using Dreamweaver CS6 Fluid Grid Layout.

I've researched the stackoverflow questions (and more) relating to this -

Facebook object debugger: 
"Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable."

Another answer on this site pointed out that something in the coding is resulting the  secion ending before the meta tags  - but I can't work out what it is. Code validator: there is a stray /head and body tag.

http://www.thatsrightratso.com.au/imp/lickit.html

What is it, can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you added your meta tags inside of the body tag rather than the head. Typically the head section contains metadata and resources that are not directly displayed on the page, where these meta tags were added inside of the body, where HTML is rendered onto the page.

Take a look at this screenshot I took of your code. I have highlighted the Facebook meta tags for you. You should move these up inside of the head element.

[image: Dom Elements]

```
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- title tags, stylesheets, other important items -->
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.thatsrightratso.com.au/imagesimpjewellery/lickitring9ctyellowgold.jpg">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Lickit ring, 9ct yellow gold or sterling silver, mens womens">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.thatsrightratso.com.au/imp/lickit/">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Lickit">
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Page Contents Rendered Here -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kaitebug, thank you very much. Even though in Dreamweaver I had those tags in the head, 'what facebook sees' shows it's in the body. I did not realise it had to be right up under the head tag, before anything else. So it's working great now, FB debugger is happy, there are less errors than ever on Nu Html Checker, it's raving on about 

"A charset attribute on a meta element found after the first 512 bytes.
Changing character encoding utf-8 and reparsing."

Something else to research!

BIG thank you